AutoBogus not working and throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Trying to use AutoBogus to generate fake data for the classes which does not have parameterless constructor. Was able to create the instance for most of the classes except one. It always throws

Autobogus  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : length ('-1') must be a non-negative value. (Parameter 'length')
Actual value was -1.

I understand that there is some property with in the class which might be creating this problem but not sure which attribute it is and why it occurs. I checked all the attributes for which length may be required and i have provided the minimum length and maximum length. The error thrown by AutoBogus is very generic and impossible to troubleshoot.
Stack trace:
  at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span 1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)

   at AutoBogus.AutoBinder.CreateInstance[TType](AutoGenerateContext context)
   at AutoBogus.Moq.MoqBinder.CreateInstance[TType](AutoGenerateContext context)
   at AutoBogus.Generators.TypeGenerator1.AutoBogus.IAutoGenerator.Generate(AutoGenerateContext context)
   at AutoBogus.AutoBinder.PopulateInstance[TType](Object instance, AutoGenerateContext context, IEnumerable1 members)
   at AutoBogus.AutoFaker1.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<PrepareFinish>b__0(Faker faker, TType instance)
   at Bogus.Faker1.PopulateInternal(T instance, String[] ruleSets)
   at Bogus.Faker1.Generate(String ruleSets)
   at AutoBogus.AutoFaker1.Generate(String ruleSets)
   at Bogus.Faker1.<>c__DisplayClass49_0.<Generate>b__0(Int32 i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectRangeIterator1.Fill(Span1 results, Int32 start, Func2 func)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectRangeIterator1.ToList()
   at Bogus.Faker1.Generate(Int32 count, String ruleSets)
   at AutoBogus.AutoFaker`1.Generate(Int32 count, String ruleSets)
   at ....

